# Free DNS hosting service with IP Blocker?

Tags: dns

Sorry for the wrong website, please any staff forward that to the correct site... I'm not able to access any StackExchange website except StackoverFlow (ISP problem).

Now, is there's any free DNS hosting service with IP Blocker ?

CloudFlare have that but for Pro only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

GeoScalling is a free DNS hosting provider since 2006, http://www.geoscaling.com/dns2

It's not easy to make it running an IP Blocker, but read how to do that here: http://www.geoscaling.com/dns2/wiki/short_programming_guide_for_smart_subdomains

Example of IP block script:

```
if( $remote_ip == "banned ip here" )
  $output[] = array("A", "ip to be returned for banned visitor");
else
  $output[] = array("A", "correct ip for unbanned visitors");
```

Also as the last point here ( http://www.geoscaling.com/unique.html ) says that's they can make the script you want for free!